# Reencode future that returns value from callable

Tags: java

My `Callable` returns `Map`, so when I assigns it to a `Future` and prints out its contents, it displays `{necessities=300, investment=100, savings=200}`.

But how do I actually read those values above? I tried to reassign the value I get from future `to Map<String,String>` but I get an Incompatible types error.

My map is `Map<String, String>`. Here's the `Callable` that returns the data (in `kucing.java`):

```
public Callable<Map<String, String>> getData() {
        return new Callable() {
            public Map<String, String> call() {
                return getDataFromDatabase();
            }
        };
    }
```

And here's how I retrieve the data into my `Future`

```
Future myResult = es.submit(kucing.getData());

Observable<Future> myObservable = Observable.just(myResult);

Subscriber<Future> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<Future>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(Future future) {
                Log.v(FILE_NAME,"future: " + future.toString());
                try{
                    Log.v(FILE_NAME,"future: " + future.get().toString());
                    Map<String, String> map = future.get();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(FILE_NAME,"future e: " + e.toString());
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: When you say a map, do you mean `java.util.Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner it was <String,String>. Apparently SO removes all strings in <> if I don't treat it as codes. I've updated my question above.

Comment: @imin yeah that's pobably to avoid HTML/CSS/JS injection

Comment: @imin never say *I got an error* without including the error message and the code pointed by the error if there is a stacktrace. *I got an error* isn't helpful at all for answerers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future myResult = es.submit(kucing.getData());
```

This Future has a raw type: you don't actually know what the type of its return value is (although you know that it will be an Object).

```
Map<String, String> map = myResult.get(); // Compiler error.
Object obj = myResult.get(); // OK.
```

You need to provide the full type:

```
Future<Map<String, String>> myResult = es.submit(kucing.getData());
Map<String, String> map = myResult.get();  // OK.
```

If you want to use the Future in this Observer/Subscriber pattern, you will need to replace all occurrences of `Future` with `Future<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: Sorry how do I assign the value from Future to Map?

Comment: Call the `get()` method on your `Future`, as stated in the first line of the answer. `Map<String, String> map = future.get()`.

Comment: In which case, your Future is not of type `Future<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: Hmmm... but my Callable function really return Map<String,String>. I've added the code above

Comment: `Future` is a raw type and is unsafe: how can you know what it will return? You need to use `Future<Map<String, String>>` instead.

Comment: Ouch never knew that. So where should I make the changes then?

Comment: @imin where you get the compilation warnings

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner. Your answer works for me. Unfortunately since I was trying to pass the myResult into observables, I cannot do Future<Map<String, String>> myResult since it will return Incompatible Types at Observable<Future> myObservable = Observable.just(myResult);. However your solution works if I didn't need to pass it to Observable. Any workaround this problem?